# Total Power Absorbed with KVL and KCL

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhCcvX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm looking to find the value of \$i_1\$, \$v\$, and the total power generated/absorbed.

[image]

I started by applying KVL and KCL laws:

\$B: i_1=i_2+i_3\$

\$M_1: 1V=6i_2+5V+54k\Omega\$,

\$M_2: 8V=1.8k\Omega i_3-30i_1+6I_2\$

I tried to solve for \$i_1\$ usuing a matrix, but I didn't get anything close to right answer.

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  -30  &6  &1.8k &8 \\ 
 54k  &6  &0 &-4 \\ 
 1  &-1  &-1 &0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right] $$

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for \$i_2\$ since the CCCS in the second branch is causing an integral multiple of \$i_1\$ to flow there and hence the middle \$6k\Omega\$ resistor has \$30+1=31i_1\$ flowing through it.

---

\$\text{KVL on }M_1:\$
\$
\begin{align}
-5V+(54k\Omega)i_1-1V+(6k\Omega)(31i_1)=0\\
\therefore \quad i_1(54k\Omega+186k\Omega)=6\\
\therefore i_1=\frac{6}{240k\Omega}=25 \mu A \Longleftarrow
\end{align}\$

Voltage across the central \$6k\Omega\$ resistor equals \$6k\Omega \times 31 \times 25\mu A=4.65V\$

Hence

\$\text{KVL on }M_2:\$
\$
\begin{align}
4.65V-8-(1.8k\Omega\times 30)i_1-\nu=0\\
\therefore \nu=-4.7 V \Longleftarrow
\end{align}\$

---

Calculations for power dissipation are then easy to take up from this point onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Your M1 is: 1V=6i2+5V+54kΩ

The first mistake is that 1V and 5V have the same polarity so your equation should be written as :
1V+5V=6i2+54kΩ

The second mistake is that you can **Not** add voltage values to resistance values, I think you forgot to multiply the 54K Resistor by its current to get the voltage across it and then you can insert the voltage value in the equation.

From KCL : The current in the 6K resistance is 31*i1

M1: "Left Loop"

-5 + 54*i1 + 6*(i1 + 30*i1) = 0

**i1 = 48 mA**

M2: The total loop or the outline loop

-5 + 54*i1 - 1 + v - 1.8*30*i1 + 8 = 0

**V = -2 volts**

*I feel like there is a calculation mistake in my answer so, I'm not quite sure of my answer if it is wrong please tell me and I will try to solve it again*